# Is it possible to convert a Java double into a Python float?

Tags: java, python, javafx, javafx-8, squish

I am currently using Squish (GUI testing framework) to test a JavaFX application. I am storing the JavaFX properties into a Python dictionary and then trying to access those properties, many of which are doubles. Is there a way to convert those doubles to floats within Python so that I can then manipulate them?

```
    def compareValue(val1, val2):
if abs(val1 - val2) < 0.0001:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I am currently trying to retrieve a height property. The Squish IDE (which is a wrapper over Eclipse) shows these properties as doubles. Since the program is JavaFX, I'm assuming that these are Java doubles. When I try to use them in this function though, I get this error:

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Object' and 'Object'
    Called from:
    C:\(Omitted for IP sake)\test.py: 66
    C:\(Omitted for IP sake)\pdi_utils.py: 441
```

Comment: Python floats should be IEEE 754 conforming with 64 bits. That is the same as Java doubles.

Comment: Python seems to recognize the doubles, but I get TypeErrors whenever I try to use them in functions. And I can't figure out how to convert them to floats.

Comment: Show us some code. It's not clear how you could even put any Java thing into any Python thing without converting the Java thing into a Python thing first. I suspect you may have produced strings.

Comment: Also, along with the code, please post the exact, complete error message, including stack trace.

Comment: Just updated it to clarify some things.

Comment: What Squish version are you using? On the Java end, are these `double`s or `Double`s?

Comment: They are doubles with a lower case. I'm using Squish 6.3.0

Comment: I'm not familiar Python or Squish but... you mention JavaFX _properties_. Are you sure they aren't an instance of `DoubleProperty` (or one of the other `Property` implementations)?

Comment: I hadn't really thought about that, I haven't ever used JavaFX before.

Comment: There is no such problem in Squish 6.3.1 or higher. Please check if a newer version of Squish resolves the problem. If not, please try to reproduce the problem with the JavaFX address book example and provide the test script code for reproducing the problem with that.